in ubuntu, how to force a bluetooth device to a fixed type
0
I bought this trackpad of brand "Keymecher", model MANO-703-UB
it works fine in Windows. but in Ubuntu, it connects to BT, but then does nothing afterwards.
I did some search, the issue is that the device is loaded by ubuntu as a "keyboard", but instead it should be a TouchPad.
is there a place I could manually edit the config so the system understands that it's a touch pad ?
I searched the model in all files under /etc, the is nothing

Please see anything on trackpads on https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Touchpad_Synaptics It has all the commands you need to check this hardware and it will show you it will not work: that device does not aupport libinput
